# Still have a problem even after activating TLS1.2 on windows7

Tags: git, github, tls1.2

I'm trying to upload a project on Github using the remote command And I got this:

> fatal: Une erreur s'est produite lors de l'envoi de la demande.
> fatal: La demande a été abandonnée : Impossible de créer un canal sécurisé SSL/TLS.
> Username for 'https://github.com': meriam-hamdaoui
> Password for 'https://meriam-hamdaoui@github.com':
> remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
> remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
> fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/meriam-hamdaoui/testing-again.git/'

I looked on Google so I update my system I activeted TLS1.2 then I excuted those two lines:

```
 $unset SSH_ASKPASS

$ git push -u origin main
```

I got "Authentication Succeeded" on a web page but still got this :

> fatal: Une erreur s'est produite lors de l'envoi de la demande.
> fatal: La demande a été abandonnée : Impossible de créer un canal sécurisé SSL/TLS.
> Username for 'https://github.com': meriam-hamdaoui
> Password for 'https://meriam-hamdaoui@github.com':
> remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
> remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
> fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/meriam-hamdaoui/testing-again.git/'

Can anyone explain to me how to fix this please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should linked to your usage of your GitHub account password, and not to TLS.

Try the same push using a [PAT (a Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) in place of your password. It should work then.

If Git never prompted for your credentials, check your git configi credential helper, and [remove the old credentials from your credentials cache](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15381198/6309).

Comment: I've got the same problem with another project and the solution didn't work with it

Comment: @maya on that other proect, what does `git remote -v` returns? (and what is your git version? `git version` would display it)

Comment: 'git remote -v'  returns

>origin  https://github.com/meriam-hamdaoui/first-website.git (fetch)
>origin  https://github.com/meriam-hamdaoui/first-website.git (push)

my git version is 2.34.1.windows.1

Comment: @maya Then the same token should work: if the credentials worked for the first repository, they should remain valid for the second, under the same ownership.

Comment: well I created another token and it worked, I guess I'll need a new token each time
thank you :)